# Result of typeof operator when function and variable names are same

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new to JavaScript, while learning hoisting I came across hoisting order as `variable declaration and initialisation> function declaration >variable declaration`. So, I tried following code

```js
var count = 1;
function count() {};
console.log(typeof count);
```

and as expected it gave output `number`. But when I tried same thing in chrome console with 1 line at a time,

[image]
it gave answer as 'Function'!! Why? Similar code I tried writing in one line it gave answer 'number'!!

[image]

What is happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @eisbehr He is running code on the same browser.

Comment: yes @eisbehr I am running code on same browser! that is chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first,you have to know the **hoisting happens before the code execute.**

then,we talk about your problem;

the first case, you execute 3 orders in three lines.the hoisting doesn't show his effect;so the code just execute accord the order you entered.

the second case, you entered the code at one line,so the actual order is:

**before executing the code**,the browser will resize your code like this

```
function count() {};
var count;
count = 1;
console.log(typeof count);
```

or

```
var count;
function count() {};
count = 1;
console.log(typeof count);
```

then ,start executing the code.
so,the typeof count returns 'number' no matter what order

Answer (score 0):

this is because if you execute one line at a time in chrome devtools you will execute in a different execution context for each line. Will be similar to execute each line on its own function..

```
(function(window){
  window.count = 1;
} )(window);
(function(window){
  window.count = function(){}
} )(window);

console.log(typeof count);
```

On the other hand, if you execute everything in one line, will be in the same execution context and as you know function declarations will be parsed first, and then the variables....

Comment: If this were the case, subsequent `let` and `const` wouldn't have fired an error.